# create an excel formula to autofill a column based on data in other columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have this out of class research project that is dealing with a lot of data. I dont want to manually copy and drag down the data as I have thousands of cells to do this for. Here is a picture of some data so I can explain what I am doing.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JWA0.png)

I have multiple titles of a baseball card pack and under that I list the cards in the pack and their price. I want to move the title in B to A for all the baseball cards in the pack. Here is a picture to make that more clear: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvGDP.png)

My thoughts on the formula to do that would be among the lines of if C[i] column is 0, j=i, A[j++] column is equal to B[i] until B[j] is true and C[j] is false. I have no experience with excel but this would really save so much of my time on this project.

EDIT: After successfully figuring out how to fill column A with the titles, how would I lock the values so that the formula doesn't update them anymore. So if I sort the data and the order is rearranged, the cards will continue to have the proper title. So far I am just copying the title column to notepad, recopying and the pasting it in column A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess column C is the price, so when a title appears, then there is no price, is a blank cell. So if that is true you could use:

```
=IF(C2="";B2;A1)
```

I tested with some data and it worked perfect (except for row number 1, but you could handle it with another IF)

Here's my data (please, note my excel is spanish, so my formula is in spanish)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response but it keeps giving me an error. I created a small data set like you did and in A2 my formula is =IF(C2=" ";B2;A2). it then gives me an error with the formula

Comment: @mileyk The error is probably from the code referencing the cell that it's in. I believe from the image in the post, that the code in cell A2 needs to have the A2 switched to A1.

Comment: I got it to work. I needed to manually input the title for A1 and then in A2 I used =IF(C2=" ",B2,A1)

Comment: @mileyk you must input `C2=""`, not `C2=" "`. Note the difference. `""` equals to nothing. `" "` equals to 1 space. My formula uses `""`, not `" "`. Also, yes, you had to manually input row 1, as I said in my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Usually with excel coding, since there aren't loops, instead I use a lot of if-then statements. The following code worked on my sample data (sorry not sure how to include an image):

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B2),A1,IF(ISBLANK(C2),B2,A1))
```

The first isblank check is for the blank rows you have interspersed in your data.

For this code, you will need to have a blank 1st row, and insert it in cell A2.

Comment: to include an image, when you are typing the answer, in the upper ribbon there is an image control that does it. When you click on it, it will ask you to upload your image. Try it!